# Picasso doesn't load images from HTTP links in API 28

Tags: android, image, http, picasso

So I've recently faced the problem where only images from HTTPS links load successfully, and all other images don't. This happened when I switched to API 28. It never did this before 28. It fails silently on all images that it fails to load, or only says "Unsatisfiable request". This is on version `2.71828`

Answer (score 6):

Turns out that according [Network Security Configuration page](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted), `Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.`

The solution is to include `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` inside the `application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`, and that's it.

This is the issue, although using Glide in Api level 28 and trying to access the same image will actually let you know that this is the issue in LogCat, while Picasso fails silently, but that's fine.